# How do I match none, one or two value in one string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string which can include none, one or two values. In case there are two value they are separated by a colon `:`, also if the first value should be empty the second (only value) would be prefixed by with a colon.

The first value can be composed of pretty any character alphanumeric and special characters, the second value only of alphanumeric characters. Therefore a colon is not a distinct separator.

I tried some regular expression, most of them work fine for only one value, or two values without a colon in the first but if the first one is empty the regex returns the whole string as first value.

My actual code looks like:

```
if ($string =~ m/^(.+)(\:(\w+)|)$/){  
    $value1 = $1 || '';    
    if ($3){$value2 = $3}
}
```

This one works for empty string, only first value, two values without colon in first value.

**Edit**:

String could be:

- `Hello World!` (only one value: value1='Hello World!')
- `This is a test:123` (two values: value1='This is a test' value2='123')
- `:Banana` (only one value: value2='Banana')
- `T3-76:` (only one value: value1='T3-76:')
- `Book:Title:Mysql` (two values: value1='Book:Title' value2='Mysql')

The main problem is how to make a difference between a one value string which includes a colon **and** some text after the colon and a two values string with no colon in the first value. I should probably assume that if this case happen it is a two value string.

**Edit2**

If it makes it easier the code could be modified to **not** match an empty string.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: See edited version of the question

Comment: How do you know if "abc:def" is one value (containing a :) or two values separated by :?

Comment: See Alexander's answer and my comment on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use `split` with a negative lookahead assertion:

```
my ($a, $b) = split(/:(?!.*:)/, $string);
```

Note that empty values may either be `undef` or the empty string.

Comment: Seems to work. I'll will just have to make sure for undefined string as you say. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then the interpretation is ambiguous. 
Consider "1:2". This could be interpreted as first value being 1, second value being 2. However, since the first value can contain special characters (such as ':'), this might also be interpreted as just the first value being "1:2".

How do you expect your "interpreter" to work in this case?

EDIT:

Have you thought about using split? It will return an array.

If array is empty => string was empty.

If array is size one => first element in array is value1

If array has multiple elements => last element in array is value2, and all other elements before that concatenated is value1.

Does that help?

Comment: As mentioned in the edited version of my question I think I'll have to assume it's a two values string. Or maybe I have to separate both value in the string by some special separator which can not be included in the first value. I just don't know which one I could use

Comment: I'll use the 'split'-solution from Peter, but your explanation helps dealing with undefined values. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^((?:(?!:[\w]*$).)*)(?::([\w]+)?)?$
```

Comment: It does not match the second value, which should be $5?

Comment: I changed it, before it did not match if there was a : in the first part. What do you mean whith $5?

Comment: I mean the value matched by the 5th parenthesis pair

Comment: There will be only 2 groups, as the ?: after the ( marks the paranthesis as not grouping. Thus you will have only $1 and if matching $2. But I agree that the solution of Peter van der Heijden is simpler and thus better.

Comment: Taking that into account, your solution seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing it with an `if` rather than as one regex doing everything. Maybe something like:

```
if ( m/^(.*):([^:]*)$/ ) { $value1 = $1; $value2 = $2; }
else { $value1 = $_; $value2 = ''; }
```

Is it important that value-2 is only alphanumeric, or is the weaker (anything not-a-colon) test OK?